# My app crashes when opened, I think it is due to swisseph.jar

Tags: java, android, crash

I have been developing an app and found that a specific code to not work which I created a new project to test to find the cause but I notice that my android app crashes when I start, here is the code

```
package my.testapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import swisseph.SweDate;
import swisseph.SwissEph;
import swisseph.SwissData;
import swisseph.SweConst;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtBox;
    int Year, Month, Day, isun, imoon, iflag;
    double Hour,Min,julDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Year = 2021;
        Month = 02;
        Day = 10;
        Hour = 14;
        Min = 30;

        julDay = SweDate.getJulDay(Year,Month,Day,Hour);

        isun = SweConst.SE_SUN;
        imoon = SweConst.SE_MOON;
        iflag = SweConst.SEFLG_SWIEPH;
        double [] xx = new double[0];
        StringBuffer serr = new StringBuffer();

        SwissEph sw = new SwissEph();
        int sunLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,isun,iflag,xx,serr);
        int moonLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,imoon,iflag,xx,serr);

        txtBox = this.findViewById(R.id.txtBox);
        txtBox.setText(
                "GDate" + Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year +
                "JDate" + julDay +
                "Sun Long" + sunLon +
                "Moon Long" + moonLon
        );
    }
}
```

I did include the swisseph jar file under the dependencies and I have placed the jar file in the libs folder under app.
I am really new to android java programming, I do apologise if this seemed really simple fix.

Comment: Include the logcat.

Comment: @EyosiyasBerketab I ran debug app on android studio using my old Samsung S5 and saved the output as a [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kn7A5_f9rnxmJXMmPL-cOS1FTq2SZaMJ/view?usp=sharing) and at line 39 there is AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: There are a lot of issues but this one caught my eye, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Check this two and try again. int sunLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,isun,iflag,xx,serr);
        int moonLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,imoon,iflag,xx,serr);

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall look into it and get back to you.

Comment: @EyosiyasBerketab I have managed to find the exact issue which was `double [] xx = new double[0];` I changed the 0 to a 6 and 6+ but the documentation I found for using swe_calc_ut shows the following
`The parameter xx is used as an output parameter containing the following info:
xx[0]:   longitude
xx[1]:   latitude
xx[2]:   distance in AU
xx[3]:   speed in longitude (degree / day)
xx[4]:   speed in latitude (degree / day)
xx[5]:   speed in distance (AU / day) `                                                                                               I am trying to get the longitude

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused due to the incorrect array size as an array can not be zero like the following:

```
double [] xx = new double[0];
```

The array should be the following:

```
double [] xx = new double[6];
```

and then referenced in:

```
 SwissEph sw = new SwissEph();
        int sunLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,isun,iflag,xx[0],serr);
        int moonLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,imoon,iflag,xx[0],serr);
```